# Gradle : How to use task's output file data in another task?

Tags: json, gradle, npm, webpack

**Problematic**

I want to update html files before packagind in war to set an HASH variable corresponding to a JS bundle compilation.

Here is what I have

```
<script th:src="@{/static/js/assistance/manifest.js}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Here is what I want at the end of the process

```
<script th:src="@{/static/js/assistance/manifest.hereIsTheHash.js}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

The hash is generated after the JS compilation which is a gradle task (see below) and is stored in a json file created after the compilation.

**What I've tried (after a thousand of another try)**

In order to update all my HTML files with a reference to my JS with HASH, I've tried this :

```
war{

    dependsOn 'createStatsJson'

    filesMatching('WEB-INF/views/**.html'){
        filter {  String line ->
                line = line.replaceAll('assistance.js', ext.assistanceJs)
                line = line.replaceAll('manifest.js', ext.manifestJs)
                line = line.replaceAll('vendor.js', ext.vendorJs)
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace *ext.assistanceJs, ext.manifestJs or ext.vendorJs* by a string, it works perfectly.

These variables are defined in another task which read a json file :

```
task createStatsJson(dependsOn: 'buildAssistanceJS') {
        def jsonFile = file('build/webpack/assistance/stats.json')
        def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)
        ext.assistanceJs = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.assistance[0]
        ext.manifestJs   = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.manifest
        ext.vendorJs     = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.vendor
}
```

This json file is created by another task :

```
task buildAssistanceJS(dependsOn: 'gulp_less', type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['--prefix', 'src/main/javascript/assistance', 'run', 'build']
}
```

**Problem**

Unfortunately, it don't works as gradle tels me that the json file does not exists. I supposed it's an build lifecycle related problem but I don't know how to achive this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `createStatsJson` task is doing everything in the `configuration` phase and nothing in the `execution` phase. The "work" should be inside a `doLast { ... }` closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working solution. Hope it will help.

```
task buildAssistanceJS(dependsOn: 'gulp_less', type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['--prefix', 'src/main/javascript/assistance', 'run', 'build']
}

def assistanceJs = ""
def manifestJs = ""
def vendorJs = ""

task createStatsJson(dependsOn: 'buildAssistanceJS') {
    doLast {
        def jsonFile = file('build/webpack/assistance/stats.json')
        def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)
        assistanceJs = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.assistance[0]
        manifestJs   = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.manifest
        vendorJs     = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.vendor
    }
}

war {

    dependsOn 'createStatsJson'

    filesMatching('WEB-INF/views/**.html'){ fichier ->
        fichier.filter {  String line ->
            line = line.replaceAll('assistance.js', assistanceJs)
            line = line.replaceAll('manifest.js', manifestJs)
            line = line.replaceAll('vendor.js', vendorJs)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
task createStatsJson(dependsOn: 'buildAssistanceJS') {
        def jsonFile = file('build/webpack/assistance/stats.json')
        def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)
        ext.assistanceJs = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.assistance[0]
        ext.manifestJs   = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.manifest
        ext.vendorJs     = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.vendor
}
```

This is a configuration closure of the createStatsJson task, not the execution phase.

**See [Gradle build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) for more information.**

Essentially, when that piece of code executes - there is still no `build/.../stats.json` (unless it's there from a previous build and you're not using the clean task).
You need to change this task to

```
task createStatsJson(dependsOn: 'buildAssistanceJS') {
    doLast {
        def jsonFile = file('build/webpack/assistance/stats.json')
        def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)
        ext.assistanceJs = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.assistance[0]
        ext.manifestJs   = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.manifest
        ext.vendorJs     = parsedJson.assetsByChunkName.vendor
    }
}
```

This will provide values in the `ex.*` variables in the execution phase.
I assume that `createStatsJson` has an explicit dependency on the relevant build tasks so that the `stats.json` (`buildAssistanceJS` I guess) file will be present when executed.

Your `war` task code suffers from the same problem. the code runs in the configuration phase, not the execution phase.

```
war{

    dependsOn 'createStatsJson'
    doLast {
      filesMatching('WEB-INF/views/**.html'){
          filter {  String line ->
                  line = line.replaceAll('assistance.js', ext.assistanceJs)
                  line = line.replaceAll('manifest.js', ext.manifestJs)
                  line = line.replaceAll('vendor.js', ext.vendorJs)
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand my mistakes. I already tried your solution before and the problem was that filesMatching is never executed in the doLast execution lifecycle. It result in a non replaced files in my war.